# How to make computer generate predefined set of numbers in Swift?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

I want to make the computer generate predefined set of numbers one-by-one. How is it possible in Swift? Is it possible using arrays?

For example: I want to generate `[1,2,3,4]` in that same order one-by-one. By generate I mean to show up like how random numbers show up when you type in `arcrandom_uniform()`.

Example:

```
var randomNumber = [1,2,3,4,5]
var guessInt = guess.text.toInt()
```

Then when I type ..

```
if Int(randomNumber) == guessInt {

//conditions


}
```

The error shows as : `Cannot assgn to the result of ths expresson`
Sometimes I get the error as `Int' is not convertible to '[Int]' swift`

The code won't work! Help ?

Here's the code for @David Skrundz :

` @IBAction func guessButton(sender: AnyObject) {
        var randomNumber = [1,2,3,4,7,8,9,5]
        var guessInt = guess.text.toInt()

```
    func generator() -> () -> Int {
        var currentIndex = 0
        let array = Array(1...5)
        func generate() -> Int {
            let value = array[currentIndex++]
            if currentIndex >= array.count {
                currentIndex = 0
            }
            return value
        }
        return generate
    }

    let gen = generator()
    gen() // Returns 1
    gen() // Returns 2
    gen() // Returns 3
    gen() // Returns 4
    gen() // Returns 1

     let answer = gen()


        if answer == guessInt {
            resultLabel.text = "Bingoo..! "}
        else {
            resultLabel.text = "Oh such a bad guesser! It was a \(answer)"
            }

    println(answer)
}
```

` 
Any idea how to fix this code the problem mentioned below ! ? Please !

Comment: What is "generate" ?

Comment: Welcome to SO. You need to be clear and specific in your questions This question is too vague. What do you mean "predefined set of numbers"? You want a string of random numbers that is repeatable?

Comment: How does a computer generate random numbers? In the same manner I want the computer to generate for example '1' the first time, '3' the second time. How to do that in swift?

Comment: No offense, but you are asking about something below the basic stuff here. At least this is how I understand the question. You really need a good programming book.

Comment: No brother!  I may admit that I am no good programmer better than you. But you answer this question. You're a champ! Champ!

Comment: @EugeneSh. I have updated the question details!

Answer (score 0):

You may want the range operator:

```
for index in 1...5 {
    println("\(index)")
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Nice idea! Lemme try that and see, but I right now need to apply it in a 'if' command!

Comment: @ShahamKampala Help for `if` is in this chapter of the documentation about the basics: https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/ControlFlow.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH9-ID127

Comment: One small doubt @EricD.  So why won't this code work? Any idea ?
`var randomNumber = [1,2,3,4,5]
var guessInt = guess.text.toInt()`

`if Int(randomNumber) == guessInt {

//conditions


}`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to generate the next element in a repeating sequence, you could use

```
func generator() -> () -> Int {
    var currentIndex = 0
    let array = Array(1...4)
    func generate() -> Int {
        let value = array[currentIndex++]
        if currentIndex >= array.count {
            currentIndex = 0
        }
        return value
    }
    return generate
}
```

And to use it:

```
let gen = generator()
gen() // Returns 1
gen() // Returns 2
gen() // Returns 3
gen() // Returns 4
gen() // Returns 1
```

Comment: The code works perfect! But the resultLabel shows : "Oh such a bad guesser! It was a [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]"  But what I want is that : See: instead of the computer saying: "Oh such a bad guesser! It was a [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]"... it should say...**first if I enter 2 then "Oh such a bad guesser! It was a 1..then if I enter 2 ..the computer should say : "Bingoo..! " Bcoz...the nxt number in the array is 2 ..! That's what we want !**

Comment: Use `var guessInt = guess.text.toInt()` and `let answer = gen()` then you can do `if guessInt == answer { ... }`

Comment: Lemme try..! and I'll let you know soon !

Comment: The code works perfectly ! Thanks for that ! But now, the problem is that : it selects one number from the array and that is 2..! And when I hit the button and enter another number in the text field, the number still generated by the computer from the array is 2. It's always 2. Like, when I enter the next number in the text field, the number generated by the computer from the array should change to the next number in the array right ? What should I do for that, Sir ?

Comment: I have updated the code in the Question Details section :)